# Number method in javascript removes the insignificant zeros when coverting string to a number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, javascript-objects

Code I am Using
Function addDecimalPoint(num){

```
return Number((num).toFixed(1));
```

}

addDecimalPoint(10);

Comment: I expect 10.0 but the output is 10. Any solution for making the out put 10.0?

Comment: `(10).toFixed(1)` is `"10.0"`. This will be a string. A number doesn’t have the concept of “amount of insignificant zeros”.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step on what your code does:-

1. Converts `num` to a string with a fixed precision upto `1` decimal place.
2. Tries to parse and create a `Number` object from the string obtained in the previous step.

From what you're trying to achieve, step 2 is completely unnecessary, and hence, the correct way the achieve the desired behaviour would be to just do the following:

```js
return num.toFixed(1);
```

Comment: tofixed returns the output as a string but i want the output to be number and 10.0 (.0 as demcimal)